# How to refresh an activity when a child activity (theme:dialog) is closed?

Tags: android, dialog

I have an activity A and when a user clicks on a button, a dialog appears(which is an Activity B with dialog theme), there he can click on a button and after that dialog disapper and user returns to the activity A . How can I refresh the activity A's UI so the users do not have to go back to the home and open again the activity A?
I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: Depend on what u want to update on Dialog close because Dialog is also part of Activity so on click of Button you can access views from Activity layout and update with latest values without opening Activity again

Comment: Can you offer some code on how to do that?

Comment: Peter: what u want to update on dialog close?

Comment: I want to change a textview. So imagine there is a textview in actvity A. In a dialog a user give a string, and when close the dialog and return to the activity A the textview value should be the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use startActivityForResult() - setResult() - onActivityResult() pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the ActivityLifecycle:

[image: Lifecycle]

When the activity A is showing up to the user again, the `onResume()` method is called. So do your updating stuff inside this method and your data is refreshed every time the activity is showing up again.